# How do you use an expression when assigning a variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

In a pipeline, I want to have the strings "feature-api" an "feature.api" available.
I was trying to do that with an expression, but not successful until now.

I tried several options:

```yaml
  variables:
    appNameDash: ${{ parameters.WebappName }}   # successfully filled with 'feature-api'
    appNameDots: ${{ replace($(appNameDash),'-','.') }}
    appNameDots: $[ replace(appNameDash,'-','.') ]
    appNameDots: $(replace($(appNameDash),'-','.'))
```

None of them works. I get either an error message or an unexpected result.

I now simply use two parameters. But is it possible do to what I tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the solution myself.

This is the syntax that works:

```
appNameDash: ${{ parameters.WebappName }}
appNameDots: $[ replace('${{ parameters.WebappName }}','-','.') ]
```

After this the two variables have the correct values: 'feature-api' and 'feature.api'.

I hope someone else is not struggling for hours.